# How to implement GUI with effects from photoshop files by using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF on C# to implement GUI follow the photoshop file design.

I use Microsoft Expression Blend to import that photoshop file, but It can not import effects without using "Flatted Image" option. This make me can not edit GUI flexibility, the effects that were contained in the photoshop file are Drop Shadow, Inner Shadow, Outer Glow, Inner Glow, Bevel and Emboss, Gradient Overlay...

Is there any way to use these effects in WPF, or is there any way to implement these effects?

Many thanks!

T&TGroup

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [WPF Shader Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)